# Ember - sort array by multiple properties in multiple directions

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js

I need to sort a collection of Ember Models by multiple properties, and not necessary in the same direction/order. I.e. I need to sort by property *a* in **ascending** order and by property *b* in **descending**. Is there a way to achieve this?

#### Update

I tried setting the `sortAscending` property to a array, but it is not working.
After looking into the source it seems that this functionality is not supported out of the box(yet).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your ArrayController:

```
sortProperties: ["propA:asc", "propB:desc"]
sortedModel: Ember.computed.sort("model", "sortProperties");
```

Then reference `sortedModel` in your template's `#each` handler.

Answer (score 5):

I decided to create a *mixin* which allows sorting in multiple orders(directions). It extends the `SortableMixin` trying to as much backwards-compatible as possible. Actually it can be used as regular `SortableMixin`. What it adds is the `sortAscendingProperties` property which is array of sort property names(members of `sortProperty` array) which should be sorted in ascending order. If the property is in `sortAscendingProperties` it will be sorted in ascending order, otherwise it will be sorted according to `sortAscending`, which serves as kind of default.
I called the mixin the `MultiSortableMixin` although I think it is not the best name.

```
(function() {

    var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set, forEach = Ember.EnumerableUtils.forEach;

    /**
     * extends the SortableMixin by allowing sorting by multiple orders.
     *
     * sortProperties - array of strings
     * sortAscending - default sort order
     * sortAscendingProperties - properties which are listed here will be sorted in ascending order, those which are not listed - will be sorted according to sortAscending
     */
    Ember.MultiSortableMixin = Ember.Mixin.create(Ember.SortableMixin, {
        /**
         Specifies the arrangedContent's sort direction

         @property {Array} sortAscendingProperties
         */
        sortAscendingProperties: null,
        orderBy: function(item1, item2) {
            var result = 0,
                    sortProperties = get(this, 'sortProperties'),
                    sortAscending = get(this, 'sortAscending'),
                    sortAscendingProperties = get(this, 'sortAscendingProperties');

            Ember.assert("you need to define `sortProperties`", !!sortProperties);

            forEach(sortProperties, function(propertyName) {
                if (result === 0) {
                    result = Ember.compare(get(item1, propertyName), get(item2, propertyName));
                    //use default sortAscending if propertyName is not listed in sortAscendingProperties
                    var sa = (sortAscendingProperties && sortAscendingProperties.indexOf(propertyName) > -1) || sortAscending;
                    if ((result !== 0) && !sa) {
                        result = (-1) * result;
                    }
                }
            });

            return result;
        },
        //overrided to add more watched props. TODO - the contents of this method is the same as parent's - find the way to just add watched stuff
        arrangedContent: Ember.computed('content', 'sortProperties.@each', 'sortAscendingProperties.@each', 'sortAscending', function(key, value) {
            var content = get(this, 'content'),
                    isSorted = get(this, 'isSorted'),
                    sortProperties = get(this, 'sortProperties'),
                    self = this;

            if (content && isSorted) {
                content = content.slice();
                content.sort(function(item1, item2) {
                    return self.orderBy(item1, item2);
                });
                forEach(content, function(item) {
                    forEach(sortProperties, function(sortProperty) {
                        Ember.addObserver(item, sortProperty, this, 'contentItemSortPropertyDidChange');
                    }, this);
                }, this);
                return Ember.A(content);
            }

            return content;
        }),
    // unneeded in this mixin, overrided to disable functionality from SortableMixin. TODO - find a way to just remove it
        sortAscendingDidChange: Ember.observer(function() {
            //empty
        }, 'sortAscending')
    });

})();
```

Usage example:

```
App.ThingsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(Ember.MultiSortableMixin, {
    sortProperties: ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'], 
    sortAscending: false,
    sortAscendingProperties: ['prop2', 'prop3'], 
    //your stuff
});
```

In this example the content of `ThingsController` will be sorted by *prop1* - in descending order, then by *prop2* and *prop3* - both in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

This is no out of the box functionality of Ember. But looking at the [code of SortableMixin](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/sortable.js#L63) one can see that it uses Ember.compare to compare two entities:

```
orderBy: function(item1, item2) {
    var result = 0,
        sortProperties = get(this, 'sortProperties'),
        sortAscending = get(this, 'sortAscending');

    Ember.assert("you need to define `sortProperties`", !!sortProperties);

    forEach(sortProperties, function(propertyName) {
      if (result === 0) {
        result = Ember.compare(get(item1, propertyName), get(item2, propertyName));
        if ((result !== 0) && !sortAscending) {
          result = (-1) * result;
        }
      }
    });

    return result;
  },
```

And [Ember.compare](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/core.js#L159) contains a check on the [**Comparable Mixin**](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/comparable.js):

```
var Comparable = Ember.Comparable;
  if (Comparable) {
    if (type1==='instance' && Comparable.detect(v.constructor)) {
      return v.constructor.compare(v, w);
    }

    if (type2 === 'instance' && Comparable.detect(w.constructor)) {
      return 1-w.constructor.compare(w, v);
    }
  }
```

Therefore my proposed solution is:

**1** - Add an additional field to your models which contains a wrapper object of all your sortingProperties, e.g. "combinedAandB"

```
App.YourModel = Ember.Object.extend({
a : null,
b : null,
combinedAandB : function(){
  // the following Object should implement SortableMixin
  var comparator = App.AandBComparator.create(this.get("a"), this.get("b"));
  return comparator;
}.property("a","b")
```

**2** - Your ComparatorModel (App.AandBComparator) should implement the Comparable Mixin. Inside this comparation method respect your desired sorting behaviour (prop a ascending and prop b descending).

**3** - Now you could instantiate an ArrayController and sort it based on your combined property:

```
var yourModelController = //whereever you may get that one from
yourModelController.set("sortProperties", "combinedAandB");
```

**Note:** This is just a spontaneous idea i got when reading your requirement. I have not yet implemented this. So this is likely not perfect :-)

Comment: took some time to get to it, but even before trying this: this idea can be good when sort properties are known beforehand, but i want to be able to specify sort properties and directions at run-time. Still doable using your approach, but seems to be clumsy and not elegant. I'm thinking now about extending the `SortableMixin` with required functionality..