# Ember sorting not working?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember js.

```
ac = [
      {"name" : "Arasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Brasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Crasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Corasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Cddasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Dcprasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Ewasadrrrrrrr", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Wrasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Axrasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Sxasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Weasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "Saasad", "price": 350.50},
      {"name" : "prasad", "price": 350.50}
     ]
abc = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    model: ac.sortBy('name'),
    sortProperties: ['price'],
    sortAscending: false
  })
```

after sorting, I print the following element.
abc.toArray()[0]
Object {name: "Dcprasad", price: 350.5, **ember_meta**: Meta}

Any suggest, how to sort the array of objects in ember js ?

Actually my real requirement is sort by price and name also.
highest price first, if prices are equal then sort by name ascending.

Thanks,
Prasad.

Comment: What does your template look like?

Answer (score 1):

This post should be helpful: [Ember - sort array by multiple properties in multiple directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999132/ember-sort-array-by-multiple-properties-in-multiple-directions)

Also, here is a jsbin detailing it: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cevivahiso/14/edit

Comment: Can I define "ac" array value in controller, because my route have many variables and some logic also.

Comment: Yep, you can change the array to be sorted by redefining "model" in the .sort() computed property inside the arrayController: [link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jegupagisi/1/edit)

Comment: @DurgaPrasad please mark this as the answer if it satisfies your question

Comment: Hi webster, sorry for late reply
In my route file, setup controller section
sortProperties: ["expense:desc", "name:asc"]
inaLits = Ember.computed.sort(model.acRecords.filterBy('is_rejected', false), "sortProperties")

controller.set 'abcLits', inaLits.toArray()+inbLits.toArray()

it returns computed array, shall I know how to convert an array .